# Saving basic data in Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple layout when the app is ran, just allowing the user to input some text, and if the text is right, the score counter will save the data received, and not run the for loop again

```
@IBAction func checkAnswer(sender: AnyObject) {
    while canAdd {
        if output.text == "hi" {
            canAdd = false
            rightOrWrong.text = "Right!"
            scoreTotal += 1
            count.text = String(scoreTotal)
        } else {
            canAdd = true
            rightOrWrong.text = "Try again!"
        }
    }
}
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this in a while loop? And what is canAdd supposed to do?

Comment: It is a while loop because I only want the score to increment one time, if the user keeps submitting their score will continue to go up. The canAdd variable is a Boolean, basically if the user get's the right answer, it set's it to false, so they can't score higher than one, and if they don't score, they can continue to try to answer until they get it right. @LyndseyScott

Answer (score 0):

As your code stands now, if the user were to enter a wrong number, your loop would be performed over and over again an infinite number of times since `canAdd` would always equal true.

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of a while loop... A while loop will continue to perform over and over and over again without pausing or waiting for user input as long a certain condition is met, so your current while loop can run forever thousands of times per second thus probably preventing user interaction and potentially crashing your program.

If you only want to score to increment/not increment once each time the button is pressed, you don't need to use the while loop. Just add your canAdd condition to your current if conditional. I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
@IBAction func checkAnswer(sender: AnyObject) {

    if output.text == "hi" && canAdd == true {
        canAdd = false
        rightOrWrong.text = "Right!"
        scoreTotal += 1
        count.text = String(scoreTotal)
    } else {
        canAdd = true
        rightOrWrong.text = "Try again!"
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I save the data, if the user scored 1 point, how would I use NSUserDefaults or CoreData?

Comment: @JustinR. Oh, just saw your comment... You also want the data to persist between app launches?